# How to get user input in windows forms with array

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding in C# and I am trying to use windows forms. I want to do a code where it gets the coordinates from a user 10 times and puts it in a stack.

```
Stack mystack =new stack(); 
For(X=0,X>6,X++)
{
Int row = 0

Int column=0
Console.Writeline("enter your row");
row=Console.Readline();
Console.Writeline("Enter your column");
column=Console.Readline()
mystack.Push(row,column);
```

The problem is that when I try to implement console.readline and writeline in windows forms it doesn't do anything when I use it. So I'm wondering if there is a tool I can use or a way to implement this.

Comment: if you are using Winforms, how did you intend to give the user the ability to enter something into your program? Using a Textbox maybe? Winforms gives you the oppurtunity to use a graphical interface.

Comment: Yeah it's just my game is essentially the user enters 10 inputs into a stack so I thought it'd be easier to use a for loop for it rather than do 20 text boxes for inputs.

Comment: your program is designed for a command shell interface not a graphical user interface like Winforms offers. You would not need 20 Textboxes, but only 1 and a button that allows the user to stack the number that was typed into the textbox. So also no need for a loop. He could type the second number into the same textbox and than hit the stack button again

Answer (score 0):

You can build a few types of applications with C#; two of them are Console Applications and Windows Forms Applications.

Console Applications are just like the `cmd`, but with your code running in it. Therefore you can use the `Console.Write`, `Console.WriteLine`, and `Console.Readline` functions.

Windows Forms Application is a different kind of app that supports GUI. You can add buttons, text boxes, images, and more to build a graphical user interface where the user can interact with your application. In a Windows Forms Application you **can't** use the `Console` functions, as the console isn't available for the user.

I suggest adding two text boxes and a button to accomplish the task you want with a Windows Forms App.

- TextBox 1: Row
- TextBox 2: Column
- Button: Pushes both values into the stack.

> You can learn more about [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) by looking into the official tutorial on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 0):

**1**. right click on windows form project. in the `application section` put `output type` to the `console Application`:

[image]

**2**. use this code:

```
        Stack mystack = new Stack();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("enter your row");
            row = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your column");
            column = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            mystack.Push(new object[] { row, column });
        }
```

Comment: Oh thanks. If I change the output to console application will I still be able to use text boxes and message boxes?

Comment: @AbdiL Yes. You will have both a form and a console

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to get user input in Windows Forms to populate a data structure that your code shows as an `Stack`. The way you would go about this in Winforms is very different from how you would do it in a Console application because UI programming is event driven.

You can use the designer to populate your main Form (for example) with labels, textboxes (in this case `NumericUpDown`) and buttons. The code behind the UI responds to events that happen when keys are pressed or buttons are clicked.

[image: screenshot]

I hope this minimal code example can get you started:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonAdd.Click += onAdd;
        buttonContinue.Enabled = false;
    }
    Stack<Point> _myStack = new Stack<Point>();
    private void onAdd(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myStack.Push(
            new Point(
                int.Parse(numericTextBoxColumn.Text),
                int.Parse(numericTextBoxRow.Text))
            );
        buttonAdd.Enabled = _myStack.Count < 10;
        buttonContinue.Enabled = !buttonAdd.Enabled;
        textBoxMultiline.Text = 
            string.Join(
                Environment.NewLine,
                _myStack.Select(_ => $"Col {_.X} Row {_.Y}").ToArray());
    }
}
```